# Linux AD integration, unable to login when using Windows Server 2012 DC

Tags: active-directory, ldap, kerberos, sssd

I am trying to integrate my CentOS 6.6 servers into Active Directory. I've followed [this](https://www.redhat.com/en/resources/integrating-red-hat-enterprise-linux-6-active-directory) guide from Red Hat using configuration 3 (SSSD/Kerberos/LDAP). When using a Windows Server 2008 R2 server as the domain controller w/ IMU enabled, everything works perfectly.

However, when I use a Windows Server 2012 R2 server w/ IMU enabled, I am able to acquire a kerberos ticket, join the domain, search LDAP, but as soon as I try to login in as an AD user from the console, I get this error message in /var/log/messages:

> Jun  6 11:12:30 test [sssd[krb5_child[4760]]]: Preauthentication failed

And /var/log/secure shows these error messages:

> Jun  6 11:12:15 test login: pam_sss(login:auth): received for user aduser@domain.local: 17 (Failure setting user credentials)
>
> Jun  6 11:12:17 test login: FAILED LOGIN 1 FROM (null) FOR aduser@domain.local, Authentication failure

Using `getent passwd aduser` or `getent group linuxgroup` returns successfully.

I've tried with this sssd.conf file:

```
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam
domains = domain.local
debug_level = 5

[domain/domain.local]
id_provider = ad
auth_provider = ad

ad_server = dc.domain.local

default_shell = /bin/bash
fallback_homedir = /home/%d/%u

cache_credentials = false
ldap_id_mapping = false
```

Then I read [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1134942) bug report. So, I changed my sssd.conf file to this:

```
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
reconnection_retries = 2
services = nss,pam
debug_level = 5
domains = domain.local

[nss]
debug_level = 5

[pam]
debug_level = 5

[domain/domain.local]
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = krb5
chpass_provider = krb5
debug_level = 5

ldap_uri = ldap://dc.domain.local/
ldap_sasl_mech = GSSAPI
ldap_schema = rfc2307bis

ldap_user_search_base = dc=domain,dc=local
ldap_user_object_class = user

ldap_user_home_directory = unixHomeDirectory
ldap_user_principal = userPrincipalName

ldap_group_search_base = dc=domain,dc=local
ldap_group_object_class = group

ldap_access_order = expire
ldap_account_expire_policy = ad
ldap_force_upper_case_realm = true

ldap_referrals = false

krb5_server = dc.domain.local
krb5_realm = DOMAIN.LOCAL
krb5_canonicalize = false

enumerate = false
cache_credentials = false
```

I've cleared my SSSD cache and restarted the service. Yet I am unable to login.

I am getting this error now in /var/log/messages:

> Jun  6 11:21:43 test [sssd[krb5_child[1546]]]: Permission denied

I'm seeing this error in /var/log/sssd/krb5_child.log:

> (Sat Jun  6 11:21:43 2015) [[sssd[krb5_child[1387]]]] [sss_get_ccache_name_for_principal] (0x2000): krb5_cc_cache_match failed: [-1765328243][Can't find client principal aduser@DOMAIN.LOCAL in cache collection]
>
> (Sat Jun  6 11:21:43 2015) [[sssd[krb5_child[1387]]]] [create_ccache] (0x0020): 575: [13][Permission denied]

Now, this is where it gets strange. As root, if I su to any AD domain user it actually works and home directory is auto created. I am about to concede defeat and just stick with the 2k8 DC.

Comment: I also experienced the same issue on a couple servers but found that my root partition was full preventing the login as a normal user but not root...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can not give a more qualified answer without seeing the `sssd` debug logs, but the bug report you're referring to only had performance implications, not functional.

The reason you're able to `su` to the account from `root` is that the PAM stack normally includes `pam_rootok.so` module that bypasses authentication with `pam_sss`. Given the auth from `root` works, we at least know that retrieving identity information works, but not auth.

I would recommend adding more information to this question either here or on the sssd-users list. Most importantly, `sssd` debug logs with a high `debug_level` from the domain section and the `krb5_child.log`.

Please find more information in the [troubleshooting document](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112015500/https://sssd.io/docs/users/troubleshooting.html) on the SSSD wiki.

Comment: You were right that bug has been fixed and providers can be set to AD even when using Windows Server 2012. I setup a new system from scratch and double checked if I was missing a step. Turned out when testing integration w/ 2k12, I installed oddjobd but forgot to install oddjob-mkhomedir resulting in SELinux blocking creation of home directories and since I was working out of root's home directory causing the entire thing to collapse. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
chmod 644 /etc/krb5.conf
```

Comment: This answer need more explanation.